# C++ object destroy

Tags: c++

I'm moving from java to c++, and i'm try to understand constructing/destructing objects.
In java when i do

```
Myclass c=createANewObject();
c=createANewObject();
```

the old c is garbage collected, and another one is created with the same name.

if i try to do the same in c++ i get strange behaviour.

```
class my_class 
{
string content;
time_t t;
public: 
my_class(string c);
~my_class();
};

my_class::my_class (string c) 
{
content=c;
cout<<"Init -" << content << "-" << t <<endl;
}

my_class::~my_class()
{
cout<<"Destroyed -" << content << "-" << t <<endl;

}

my_class get_new_object(string s)
{
   my_class c(s);
   return   c;
}

int main()
{
    my_class c=get_new_object("A");
    c=get_new_object("B");
}
```

Instead of getting

```
Init -A-
Init -B-
destr.A
destr.B
```

because first i create A, then create B, then A is destroyed, and the scope is ended so B is destroyed

I get

Init -A-1456178128
Init -B-1456178131
Destr.B-1456178131
Destr.B-1456178131

So my A is created and not destroyed, and B... is destroyed two times?

Comment: Why do you the old `A` should be destroyed? The object is still in the same scope, you merely assigned a new value to it.

Comment: And why the B is destroyed two times? the time of creation tells that the A is created and never destroyed, and B is created and destroyed TWO times

Comment: Do not compare Java garbage collection to C++'s deterministic destruction paradigm.  They are totally different animals.  In Java, we don't know when the heck the object is really destroyed, just that it will be destroyed at some time.  With C++, we know **exactly** when the object will be destroyed.

Comment: You assigned `B` to the object in main. That's why you see it the second time. Your objects aren't `A` and `B`, but rather `c` and a temporary.

Comment: This sounds like [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: @callyalater: not enough information, since he doesn't have any logging in his copy constructors nor copy assignment

Comment: @MooingDuck True, that is why I said sounds like. I was just guessing based on the most probable scenario.

Comment: @CiccioPasticcio To be honest with you, how many times a destructor is called should be the least things to get worked up over.  Reason -- you will get different results based on compiler, compiler settings, optimizations, etc.  So is it worth it to attempt to chase down and explain all of these differing answers?  As long as your code is well written, let the compiler do its job and optimize (or not optimize) copying and destruction.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, but i was thinking about memory usage, not destroyer. i was asking the question because i can't understand what happened to the first A. i thinked that A is "lost" as a memory leak, and ~B was destroying two times the same object. now i'm understanding that is no memory leak. thank you

Answer (score 8):

In Java your code does the following sequence:

- Make a new object
- Set the reference `c` to refer to that object
- Make another new object
- Release the reference `c` from the old object and make it refer to the new object
- The old object now has no references and will later be garbage collected

In C++ your code is quite different. Don't be fooled by the similar-looking syntax.  In C++ you *can* perform almost that same steps as your Java code did; by using different syntax. But the syntax you did actually use does the following:

- Make an object `get_new_object::c("A")`
- Return a copy of that object
- Destroy the `get_new_object::c`
- Make object `main::c` initialized by copying the returned copy
- Destroy the returned copy
- Make an object `get_new_object::c("B")`
- Return a copy of that object
- Destroy the `get_new_object::c`
- Update `main::c` by copying detail from the returned object
- Destroy the returned object
- (At the end of main) Destroy `main::c`

Some of the above copies may be optimized out by a process called *copy elision*. If you use a compiler switch to disable copy elision you should see all of the above steps, i.e. 5 destructors, 2 normal constructors, and (if you also add output for the other special functions), 3 copy-constructors and 1 assignment operator.

NB. In C++11 the temporary objects may be moved in and out of (if the compiler decides not to use elision) rather than copied. But I leave this out to keep the list simple.

Comment: 3rd step: Destroy the get_new_object::c. why i don't see "destroyed A" of internal C object?

Comment: I'm using `::` as pseudocode here (you can't actually refer to local variables that way)

Comment: @CiccioPasticcio that's one of the objects that copy elision can remove. With copy elision, the first call to `my_class c(s);` will construct the object directly in the memory area for main's `c`  , bypassing both the `my_class::c` and the return value object.  But this doesn't happen for the second call, because it is not initializing an object with the result.  (`c` is still elided the second time, but the return value object is not elided and that is one of the destructors you see)

Comment: Now i understand. M.M. you are the best!

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat compiler and version (`C++11`) specific.

`get_new_object` creates an entry, and returns it by value.  That may create 3 objects, 2 objects or 1.

### 3 objects

The compiler creates a stack object.
This gets a copy constructor into a temporary.
This temporary uses another copy constructor to move into C

### 2 objects

A more smart compiler loses the middle temporary.

### 1 object

A very smart compiler realize that only one result matters. `c++11` helps by move constructors.

The copy/move constructors will be created, but not reporting in your code.

The destructors accurately describe the number of objects created (2)

### the a / b conundrum

The compiler figures it only needs A. 
Thus

```
 init A
```

When b is created, a new object is made.  This is copy constructed into `c`

```
Init b
```

Then the b temp is destroyed.

```
Destr b
```

Then `c` is destroyed

```
destr b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    my_class get_new_object(string s)
    {
    my_class c(s);
    return  c;
    }

    int main()
    {
    // Sequence of events:
    //    - get_new_object() called
    //    - Inside get_new_object() "my_class c() instance created on stack and constructor called --> This is the first constructor call you see
    //    - Inside get_new_object() "return c;" statement  first creates a copy of 'c' and assigns to the my_class c in main() --> This is your second constructor call
   //     - return c; initiates destruction of the my_class c which was created inside get_new_object() since it's on the stack and the function is going out of scope  --> This is your first Destructor call
   //     - main ends --> This is when the my_class c of main() goes out of scope and the destructor is called again.
    my_class c=get_new_object("A");
    c=get_new_object("B");
    }
```